# How to find out how node web server is started on our server?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, node.js, process

So we have a bunch of old (like 2 years) Ubuntu 14.04 servers running production application, which has an API endpoint in Node.

But we have no idea how to start/stop/restart node on it.. it just comes up when we reboot the machine :)

I have tried popular answers like pm2, forever, systemd, and StrongLoop - none seem to be used to start node.
I also looked at /etc/init and init.d, and cant find anything that looks like it.

Any suggestions how to find it?

The Original author of the application is long gone...

The only other clue I have is `/etc/apache2/conf-available/javascript-common.conf`
Which contains

```
Alias /javascript /usr/share/javascript/

<Directory "/usr/share/javascript/">
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
</Directory>
```

When I go to that directoy, I found 2 files: 
`/usr/share/javascript/node-uuid/uuid.js` and I suppose same .min.js file, seems to be library to generate UUIDs, and I dont see any references to our application...

Also I know the app.js has app.listen(8080), so I doubt this is done by apache/nginx, but I don't know enough about node+web server setups to know...

```
 ls -alR /etc/apache2/
/etc/apache2/:
total 12
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4096 Apr  4  2017 .
drwxr-xr-x 104 root root 4096 Sep 14 11:41 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Sep 14 11:48 conf-available

/etc/apache2/conf-available:
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep 14 11:48 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Apr  4  2017 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  127 Aug 11  2013 javascript-common.conf
```

Comment: Maybe `/etc/rc.local` ?

Comment: `chkconfig: command not found` so not that...

Comment: @MrShunz not there, it only runs some corporate script, and then starts chef-client

Comment: I'm sorry, im an idiot. Node applications are built and compiled by node. But only really hosted by node in a testing environment. Prod env tend to use apache or nginx to serve the files.

I would look at apache or nginx config files for the dir paths of the compiled JS code that is your website. ( you might get lucky, if you `grep -iR "websitename" /etc/httpd/conf*`

ubuntu 14 may be using the dir name "apache2" instead of httpd. My ubuntu 14 knowledge is now a little rusty, i would need to boot up a node and look at it now.

Comment: @Arlion I just edited the question with information on what I found under `apache2` (there is no httpd there) - not sure about nginx, but there is no directory called that way in /etc

Comment: Awesome, this supports the notion that apache is serving the static js files. In that same file, can you post an `ls -alR /etc/apache2/` ?

Another Question, does the former developer has a user account and home directory on that server? It might be as easy to find where he used node to build the JS files. Copy the config files over to a newer LTS OS and recompile the JS files.

Comment: @Arlion added ls output in question. I looked at his user's directory - nothing useful :(

Comment: I also dont think the js files were built/compiled in the modern way.. it seems to be source js files are being used/served with ExpressJS and routes files

Comment: @Carmageddon Can you post the `ls -alR /var/www/html`
What I am looking for is that there is no web server root directory. This config only appears to handle `http://<serverwebaddress>/javascript/`

So, let's see if the JS files are in `/var/www/html` and would answer where the webserver root is located.

Comment: @Arlion `ls: cannot access /var/www/html: No such file or directory` (I am root)

Comment: `ls -alR /var/www/` Please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83176/discussion-between-arlion-and-carmageddon).

Answer (score 0):

For a time, before Ubuntu finally gave up on upstart and switched to systemd, it was popular to use supervisor to start Node (and some who follow obsolete Internet tutorials still attempt to use it). Run `supervisorctl` and it will show the status of any applications it manages.

Comment: supervisorctl is not installed, so not that :(